# Get specific value from database to validate data

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, ms-access

I want to take a value entered by the user and validate it against known values in a database.

I'm using VB.net (VS 2010) as a front end winform and dumping data into MSAccess. I have a table with values such as min weight and max weight, the user will enter a weight, and it needs to fall between the min weight and max weight values in the table.

I'm already created an open connection with the database I need, I guess I just don't know enogh VB.net and SQL to make it do what I want.

I want to have the user enter the Primary key of the table with the min weight and max weights and then use that to bring in the min max weights, then check the weight the user entered against the min max weights.

Here is all the code; the only really relevant code is the validate button click at the bottom. I just thought possibly this would give more context. Any point in the right direction will help, even if it gives me better keywords to google. Thanks!

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
Dim dbInsert As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
Dim dbConnect As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim Line As String = Environment.NewLine
Dim Job As VariantType

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Try
        dbConnect.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\crabara\Desktop\Project Alpha 3\MDB.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
        dbConnect.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + Line + "Main Database Not Found" + Line + "Check form_AccessMaintenance source code" + Line + "Database Path", "Critical Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Me.Close()
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim Part As String, Job As String, Emp As String, Weight As String, Oven As String

    Part = txtPart.Text
    Job = txtJob.Text
    Emp = txtEmp.Text
    Weight = txtWeight.Text
    Oven = txtOven.Text

    If ((Job.StartsWith("JH") And Job.Length = 10) Or Job.Equals("MT")) = False Then
        MsgBox("Please input the correct Job Number.")
        txtJob.Clear()
        txtJob.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Part.Length = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Please input the correct Part Number.")
        txtPart.Clear()
        txtPart.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Emp.Length = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Please input the correct Employee Number.")
        txtEmp.Clear()
        txtEmp.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Weight.Length = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Please input the correct Weight.")
        txtWeight.Clear()
        txtWeight.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Oven.Length = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Please input the correct Oven Number.")
        txtOven.Clear()
        txtOven.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    dbInsert.Parameters.Add(dbInsert.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "Part"
    dbInsert.Parameters.Item("Part").Value = txtPart.Text
    dbInsert.Parameters.Add(dbInsert.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "Job"
    dbInsert.Parameters.Item("Job").Value = txtJob.Text
    dbInsert.Parameters.Add(dbInsert.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "Emp"
    dbInsert.Parameters.Item("Emp").Value = txtEmp.Text
    dbInsert.Parameters.Add(dbInsert.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "Weight"
    dbInsert.Parameters.Item("Weight").Value = txtWeight.Text
    dbInsert.Parameters.Add(dbInsert.CreateParameter).ParameterName = "Oven"
    dbInsert.Parameters.Item("Oven").Value = txtOven.Text
    Try
        dbInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Foam(Part,Job,Emp,Weight,Oven) VALUES(txtPart.Text, txtJob.Text, txtEmp.Text, txtWeight.Text, txtOven.Text);"
        dbInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        dbInsert.Connection = dbConnect
        dbInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Data has been successfully submitted" + Line + txtPart.Text)
        txtPart.Clear()
        txtJob.Clear()
        txtEmp.Clear()
        txtWeight.Clear()
        txtOven.Clear()
        Control.MousePosition.Equals(txtPart)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub txtJob_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    txtJob.Clear()
End Sub
Private Sub txtJob_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim Job2 As String

    Job2 = txtJob.Text

    If txtJob.Text.Length = 8 Then
        txtJob.Text = "JH" + Job2
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub btnValidate_Click_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnValidate.Click
    Dim Pcr As Integer
    Pcr = txtPcr.Text

    Try

        dbInsert.CommandText = "SELECT MoldVinylWeightMin FROM PROCESS_INFO where PCRNumber= '" & txtPcr.Text & "'"""
        'How can I get this data I've selected into a variable I can work with, also not sure if the above command actually works also this only gives me the min I need the max too
        dbInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        dbInsert.Connection = dbConnect
        dbInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Data has been successfully submitted" + Line + txtPart.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
  End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below code will help you

```
    Dim table = New DataTable()
    Dim adp As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT MoldVinylWeightMin FROM PROCESS_INFO where PCRNumber= '" & txtPcr.Text & "'", dbConnect)
    adp.Fill(table)
    If table.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
        If table.Rows(0).Item("MoldVinylWeightMin") <> YourField Then
                Display the message
        End If
    Else
        No record found
    End If
```

using this block you can get the record from the database and apply you validation.

Comment: Is this comparing fields? Ideally what I'd like to do is take moldvinylweightmin and put it into a local variable, because myfield will be a local variable and inevitably stored into a different table.